# How to backup mac data using ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, backup, file-permissions

Suddenly my Mac Mini hard drive crashed and I am trying to save data from Macintosh HD 2 in my USB case using Ubuntu. I am able to mount Macintosh HD 2 but getting this error:

> You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "Macintosh HD 2".

How to backup my data using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a byte by byte copy of your partition using [dd](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/ddcommand.htm). IMHO that would be the best choice of backup as it doesn't require any assumptions on the partition.

I'm not very familiar with this new Core Storage the macs use nowadays. I'm not really sure if you can read it without the *proper* EFI or whatever hardwars. So you might need to use a Mac to get your files out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy the files with the command

```
sudo cp -R /path/to/macdrives /home/user/newdirectory
```

obviously you need to modify the paths as needed.

You then need to take ownership of the files with a

```
cd /home/user/newdirectory
chown username *
```

(this will affect the copy of the files, not the original files on the disk).

Notice that this will likely break your original permissions on system files, so if you want to restore the OSX partition to a new Mac this isn't a convenient way. But if you just want to copy important data, then it is the easiest method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, I ran this command gksudo nautilus this command showed all the data but I cant copy data to my usb. After mounting the Macintosh HD 2 using disk utility I get this path /media/Macintosh HD 2 so how I will specify path.

Comment: OK, so the path is `/media/Machintosh HD 2`. To make sure, open a terminal and use the command `ls "/media/Machintosh HD 2"`. You should see a list of folders like `Applications, Library, home`... Now let's suppose the path to the USB drive is `/media/USB`, and you created a `backup` folder inside it, then use the first command I provided like this: `sudo cp -R "/media/Machintosh HD 2" /media/USB/backup`.

Comment: Remember to use the doublequotes `"` if the path contains spaces!

Comment: Please tell me is there any command to get permission of all files and I backup those important files instead copying all data.

Comment: Please tell me that is tati.tati * means

Comment: I'm sorry I copied the command from a personalized source and I forgot to change it, replace tati with your ubuntu user name. The command `chown user.group *` indicates that the specified user becomes the owner of the files (the asterisk means to apply to all files). If you do this directly on the files on Mahintosh HD this will skrew the default OSX permissions. This means that you probably won't be able to restore the system. If you just want to backup data, there is no problem in using the command on the files on Macintosh HD

Comment: You can copy only the files that interest you using the appropriate syntax for the copy command. Suppose you want to copy your user home, then you would use the command `sudo cp -R "/media/Macintosh HD 2/Users/username /backup/position"` where you replace username with your OSX username and `/backup/position` with the path where you want your files saved to.